# Dynamically create query a search request based on params in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.2

Here are some request to a search page I have

```
/articles?tag=tag1&author=author1
/articles?title=title1&tag=tag1
/articles?title=title1&tag=tag1&author=author1
/articles?tag=tag1
/articles?title=title1&tag=tag1&author=author1&size=medium&is_deprecated=false&has_fotos=true
```

Well, what is the most efficient way to make a request to `Article` model depending on a query? I wouldn't like to do something like this

```
@articles = Article.all
@articles = Article.find_by_tag(params[:tag]) if params[:tag]
@articles = Article.where("title like ?", params[:title]) if params[:title]
@articles = Article.find_by_author(params[:author]) if params[:author]
@articles = Article.find_by_is_deprecated(params[:is_deprecated]) if params[:is_deprecated]
#...etc
```

Your thoughts?

Comment: http://www.pixellatedvisions.com/2009/04/21/passing-a-hash-of-conditions-to-find-in-rails

Comment: It was written in 2009, it's deprecated.

Answer (score 1):

No need to execute sql query each time... use ruby way.
You can use following method..

```
@articles = Article.all

@articles.select!{ |article| article.tag==params[:tag] } if params[:tag].present?

@articles.select!{ |article| article.title==params[:title]} if params[:title].present?

@articles.select!{ |article| article.author==params[:author]} if params[:author].present?

@articles.select!{ |article| article.is_deprecated==params[:is_deprecated]} if params[:is_deprecated].present?
```